# parsing table with BeautifulSoup and write in text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need data from table in text file (output.txt) in this format:
data1;data2;data3;data4;.....

Celkova podlahova plocha bytu;33m;Vytah;Ano;Nadzemne podlazie;Prizemne podlazie;.....;Forma vlastnictva;Osobne

All in "**one line**", separator is "**;**" (later export in csv-file).

I´m beginner.. Help, thanks.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import codecs

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.reality.sk/zakazka/0747-003578/predaj/1-izb-byt/kosice-mestska-cast-sever-sladkovicova-kosice-sever/art-real-1-izb-byt-sladkovicova-ul-kosice-sever')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tabulka = soup.find("table", {"class" : "detail-char"})

for row in tabulka.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')
    prvy = col[0].string.strip()
    druhy = col[1].string.strip()
    record = ([prvy], [druhy])

fl = codecs.open('output.txt', 'wb', 'utf8')
for rec in record:
    line = ''
    for val in rec:
        line += val + u';'
    fl.write(line + u'\r\n')
fl.close()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not keeping each record as you read it in. Try this, which stores the records in `records`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import codecs

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.reality.sk/zakazka/0747-003578/predaj/1-izb-byt/kosice-mestska-cast-sever-sladkovicova-kosice-sever/art-real-1-izb-byt-sladkovicova-ul-kosice-sever')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tabulka = soup.find("table", {"class" : "detail-char"})

records = [] # store all of the records in this list
for row in tabulka.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')
    prvy = col[0].string.strip()
    druhy = col[1].string.strip()
    record = '%s;%s' % (prvy, druhy) # store the record with a ';' between prvy and druhy
    records.append(record)

fl = codecs.open('output.txt', 'wb', 'utf8')
line = ';'.join(records)
fl.write(line + u'\r\n')
fl.close()
```

This could be cleaned up more, but I think it's what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternative non BS way, just for your task

```
store=[] #to store your results
url="""http://www.reality.sk/zakazka/0747-003578/predaj/1-izb-byt/kosice-mestska-cast-sever-sladkovicova-kosice-sever/art-real-1-izb-byt-sladkovicova-ul-kosice-sever"""
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
data=page.read()
for table in data.split("</table>"):
    if "<table" in table and 'class="detail-char' in table:
         for item in table.split("</td>"):
              if "<td" in item:
                  store.append(item.split(">")[-1].strip())
print ','.join(store)
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
Celková podlahová plocha bytu,33 m2,Výťah,Áno,Nadzemné podlažie,Prízemné podlažie,Stav,Čiastočná rekonštrukcia,Konštrukcia bytu,tehlová,Forma vlastníctva,osobné
```

Comment: Should be ';'.join(store) as semicolons are required between items.

Comment: Wow this is great - but you have a limit in there to just grab the first item.  How can in continue to grab ALL data in the table, including nested tables?