# Extracting a table from web with different hierarchical tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I tried to parse the table from 
https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/nebuffer-performance-chart-with-restriction-enzymes with Pythons library lxml but if I try it with some snippets of code from similar extracting versions ([How to extract tables from websites in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556048/how-to-extract-tables-from-websites-in-python)) I run into problems with `<a>-tags` and images which are displayed in this table.. 
In the end I want a text file with the following columns of this restriction enzyme table from NEB without any formatting, just plain text:

> Enzyme | Sequence | NEBuffer | % Activity in NEBuffer | Heat Inac. | Incu. Temp.

I wanted to try to extract each td of a row by its own and combine the information in a list entry:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import etree
url = "https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/nebuffer-performance-chart-with-restriction-enzymes"
tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[2]/div/div/section[@class="chart"]/table/tbody/tr')

cells = [[rows.xpath('//td/a/text()'), 
          rows.xpath('//td/text()')] for tr in rows]
print cells[1]
```

But it mixes up everything in just one entry and I do not know how to deal with those special characters like 'u and \u2122 
The first lines of the output:

```
[['AatII', u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer', 'AbaSI', 'NEBuffer 4', 'Acc65I', 'NEBuffer 3.1', 'AccI', u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer', 'AciI', u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer',
```

and I think I do not have coded that columns like the images in column 2 are skipped :/

I hope my question is detailed enough so you are able to understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `\u2122` is only the ASCII-friendly representation of the `™` unicode character. If you `print()` the string, you'll see that character instead of that. So no worries!

then, your code does not work for me:

```
tree.xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[2]/div/div/section[@class="chart"]/table/tbody/tr')
```

is returning a list, which makes it impossible to do:

```
rows.xpath('//td/a/text()')
```

so I don't get how you're getting a result. And even if it was working, there's something you don't get with XPath, it's that `//` makes the search start at the root of the document, which why you're getting every content of a `a` tag within a `td` tag, not the one inside the `tr` you're in.

On the contrary, if you use a *relative* xpath, the following would work:

```
>>> rows[0].xpath('td/a')
[<Element a at 0x2e3ff50>, <Element a at 0x2e3ff00>]
>>> rows[0].xpath('td/a/text()')
['AatII', u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer']
```

But thing is that doing so is too generic and you won't be able to keep element
in the order of interest.  And sadly, there's no automatic way to get that
interesting stuff out of it.

Then You need to take the HTML, and see that you want the `alt` of the image in
that `td`, that you want to take the content of the `span` in that other one:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="/products/r0117-aatii">AatII</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img class="product-icon" longdesc="This enzyme is purified from a recombinant source." alt="recombinant" src="/~/media/Icons/icon_recomb.gif">
        <img class="product-icon" longdesc="This enzyme is capable of digesting 1 µg of DNA in 5 minutes." alt="timesaver 5min" src="/~/media/Icons/icon_timesaver5.gif">
        <img class="product-icon" longdesc="Cleavage with this restriction enzyme is blocked when the substrate DNA is methylated by CpG methylase." alt="cpg" src="/~/media/Icons/icon_cpg.gif">
    </td>
    <td>GACGT/C</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/products/b7204-cutsmart-buffer">CutSmart™ Buffer</a>
    </td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>50*</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:red;">80°C</span>
    </td>
    <td>37°C</td>
    <td>B </td>
    <td>
        <img width="10" height="10" alt="Not Sensitive" src="/~/media/Icons/Not Sensitive.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img width="10" height="10" alt="Not Sensitive" src="/~/media/Icons/Not Sensitive.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
        <img width="10" height="10" alt="Blocked" src="/~/media/Icons/Blocked.gif">
    </td>
    <td>λ DNA</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The following is getting the values of interest from the document you linked:

```
>>> for row in rows: print row[0].xpath('a/text()'), [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[1].xpath('img')], row[2].text, row[3].xpath('a/text()'), row[4].text, row[5].text, row[6].text, row[7].text, row[8].xpath('span/text()'), row[9].text, [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[10].xpath('img')], [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[11].xpath('img')], [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[12].xpath('img')], row[13].text, row[14].text
['AatII'] ['recombinant', 'timesaver 5min', 'cpg'] GACGT/C [u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer'] 10 50* 50 100 [u'80\xb0C'] 37°C [] ['Not Sensitive'] ['Not Sensitive'] None λ DNA
['AbaSI'] ['recombinant'] None ['NEBuffer 4'] 25 50 50 100 [] 25°C [] ['Not Sensitive'] ['Not Sensitive'] None None
['Acc65I'] ['recombinant', 'timesaver 5min', 'dcm', 'cpg'] G/GTACC ['NEBuffer 3.1'] 10 75* 100 25 [] 37°C [] ['Not Sensitive'] ['Blocked by Some Combinations of Overlapping'] None pBC4 DNA
...
```

which gets all the fields.

In the end, to make it easily reuseable, here's what I'd do:

```
 enzimes = [{ 'enzime'                     : row[0].xpath('a/text()'),
              'attributes'                 : [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[1].xpath('img')],
              'Supplied NEBuffer'          : row[2].text,
              '% Activity in NEBuffer 1.1' : row[3].xpath('a/text()'),
              '% Activity in NEBuffer 2.1' : row[4].text,
              '% Activity in NEBuffer 3.1' : row[5].text,
              'CutSmart'                   : row[6].text,
              'Heat Inac.'                 : row[7].text,
              'Incu. Temp.'                : row[8].xpath('span/text()')[0] if len(row[8].xpath('span/text()')) > 0 else row[8].text,
              'Diluent'                    : row[9].text,
              'Dam'                        : [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[10].xpath('img')],
              'Dcm'                        : [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[11].xpath('img')],
              'CpG'                        : [img.attrib['alt'] for img in row[12].xpath('img')],
              'Unit Substrate'             : row[13].text,
              'Note'                       : row[14].text
            } for row in rows]
```

and for the first enzime, here's the result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(enzimes[0])
{'% Activity in NEBuffer 1.1': [u'CutSmart\u2122 Buffer'],
 '% Activity in NEBuffer 2.1': '10',
 '% Activity in NEBuffer 3.1': '50*',
 'CpG': ['Not Sensitive'],
 'CutSmart': '50',
 'Dam': [],
 'Dcm': ['Not Sensitive'],
 'Diluent': u'37\xb0C',
 'Heat Inac.': '100',
 'Incu. Temp.': u'80\xb0C',
 'Note': u'\u03bb DNA',
 'Supplied NEBuffer': 'GACGT/C',
 'Unit Substrate': None,
 'attributes': ['recombinant', 'timesaver 5min', 'cpg'],
 'enzime': ['AatII']}
```

HTH

Comment: well much thanks :o but theres another small problem you're right with the span-tag but this appears just in some cases and the case where the span-tag is not used I do not get the correct value because he cannot find a span tag to look into :/ is it possible to add a if-else statement?!

Comment: sure, check the modification I made in the last example

Comment: I think you put the bracket at the wrong position.. instead of if len(row[8].xpath('span/text()') > 0) it should be if len(row[8].xpath('span/text()')) > 0 but thanks it works fine :)