# Missing one column and redundent whitespaces/newlines in webpage scraping using lxml in python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrape [this page](http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-) in python to get the biggest table in that page into a `csv`. I'm mostly following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556133/2724299).

But I'm facing two problem:

- The column for **Strike Price** is missing
- Writing the data to csv is misaligned due to a aberrant string containing multitudes of "\r" and ending with a single "\n". This puts lot of whitespace chars in the `csv`

Following is the code I'm using. Please help me fix this two problems.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from lxml import etree
import csv

ourl = "http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=31DEC2015"

headers = {'Accept' : '*/*',
           'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
           'Host': 'nseindia.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm',
           'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

req = Request(ourl, None, headers)
response = urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

ptree = etree.HTML(the_page)
tr_nodes = ptree.xpath('//table[@id="octable"]/tr')
header = [i[0].text for i in tr_nodes[0].xpath("th")]
td_content = [[td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')] for tr in tr_nodes[1:]]

with open("nseoc.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(td_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Writing the data to csv is misaligned due to a aberrant string containing multitudes of "\r" and ending with a single "\n"

First of all, I would use `lxml.html` package, get the `text_content()` of every cell and apply `strip()` afterwards:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring   

ptree = fromstring(the_page)

tr_nodes = ptree.xpath('//table[@id="octable"]//tr')[1:]
td_content = [[td.text_content().strip() for td in tr.xpath('td')] 
              for tr in tr_nodes[1:]]
```

Here is how `td_content` would look:

```
[
    ['', '700', '-', '-', '-', '5,179.00', '-', '1,350', '4,972.25', '5,006.15', '450', '2700.00', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ''], 
    ['', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1,200', '4,710.85', '5,254.15', '150', '2800.00', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ''],
    ...
]
```

Note that the "Strike Price" is there (2700 and 2800).