# How to pull the table data that is generated with javascript from a website using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, html-table, urllib2

My goal is to get only the data from a specific table in a website. If possible, opened website could be run on the background preventing to pop-up.

I have tried [Get page generated with Javascript in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960386/2402577) answer to apply, but it dumps all the data in the site rather than only the table. My best option is to parse it from there. As alternative I have tried [How to extract tables from websites in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556133/2402577) answer but returned list object is empty.

---

As an example, I want to pull table (given information under the `Symbol Size Entry_Price Mark_Price PNL`) that is located at the bottom of the page from [this site](https://www.binance.com/en/futuresng-activity/leaderboard/7E32B49490355C9FCCAA709A1D364AA6?tradeType=PERPETUAL).

How can I achive this? While achieving it can the opened browser open on the background preventing the focus to itself?

Answer (score -1):

This code prints all HTML tables starting with index 0, 1, and so on...

```
tables1 = pd.read_html('https://www.binance.com/en/futuresng-activity/leaderboard/7E32B49490355C9FCCAA709A1D364AA6?tradeType=PERPETUAL')

tables1[0]

#or
#tables1[1]
#or
#tables[2]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation by editing your answer...

Comment: This code prints all HTML tables starting with index 0, 1 and so on

Comment: Which library does `pd` belong to?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `BeuatifulSoup or bs4 with requests` for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r=requests.get("") #url over here this will not open the browser
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    print(table)
```

This code will print all the tables and then you can see the data and use if statements to come to a conclusion.

Comment: This does not get the table at the bottom of the page