# download csv file via a website in pyhton

Tags: python, csv, download

I want to automatically download via python the csv file provided in [this](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp) website.

https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp

I am trying the usual methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556048/how-to-extract-tables-from-websites-in-python) as well as this script:

```
base_url = 'https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp#'
# 1. Download data
orig_m = (pd.read_csv(f'{base_url}.csv').dropna(how='all'))
```

Nothing has really worked so far. Can someone please help?

Comment: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp#.csv does not contain a CSV for you to download; it is unclear why you think this should work.

Comment: It contains. Please look at the link more carefully. All I want then is to use python to download this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be possible to download a .csv directly from this website. They seem to generate a new link to that file everytime you download it.

You could open the website via `python/selenium` and then download the file. Since the data is also available on the site itself a faster solution would be to download the website with `python/requests` and the parse the site with he help of `python/pandas`.

Here is a basic example.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp#").content
df_list = pd.read_html(response)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Comment: This worked like a magic. I tried first to use this approach, but I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score -4):

you can do this it download the file in same folder. you can sleep for few seconds to make sure to file is download then you can read.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'Your url'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="stats-table_wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]").click()
```

if it does not work or you want to download other files replace "//*[@id="stats-table_wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]" with other xpath from the you can select x path by:

- Right click on the element you want and click inspect
- Inspected element will be highlighted in chrome debugger. Right click
  on
- that element and bunch of options will open